# Sequel Migration: uninitialized constant Jsonb (NameError)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, padrino

I'm using [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) with [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com/) and the following migration raised the `uninitialized constant Jsonb (NameError)` error:

```rb
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table :same_table do
      add_column :not_working, Jsonb
    end
  end
end
```

The `create_table` migration for the sale table used Jsonb without issue:

```rb
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table :same_table do
      Jsonb :worked
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As by [`Sequel` source code](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_json.rb#L212), the column type should not be capitalized. In general, DSL is about defining class methods, not constants.

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table :same_table do
    #                          ⇓⇓ NOTE SYMBOL     
      add_column :not_working, :jsonb
    end
  end
end

Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table :same_table do
    # ⇓ NOTE DOWNCASE
      jsonb :worked
    end
  end
end
```